# LinqToSql + calling .Count fails in production only

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

This should be very simple, but its very frustrating.

I have a LinqToSql as below, it works fine in development but when i move the code to production it blows up on .Count

---

update, resolved the issue, but dont understand why i had to...
Please explain if you can, im confused.  The code below works fine in development, in order to get it to work in production i had to NOT use deferred typing, so...
instead of:

```
Dim val = From a In _configuration Where a.ItemKey = "Val5" Select
```

I had to use:

```
Dim val As IEnumerable(Of MyAssembly.Configuration) _
   = From a In _configuration Where a.ItemKey = "Val5" Select a
```

Why in the world would the first way work on my development server but not the production server?  They both have 3.5 SP1, etc...

---

```
   Dim val = From a In _configuration Where a.ItemKey = "Val5" Select a
    Dim valExists As Boolean = False
    If val.Count > 0 Then
        valExists = True
    End If
```

The error i get is:
System.MissingMemberException: Public member 'Count' on type 'WhereSelectListIterator(Of Configuration,Configuration)' not found.

This makes absolutely no sense to me.  The type of val is IEnumerable so why would i not be able to call .Count on this?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
  val.AsEnumerable.Count
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, try checking if val is returning null for some reason:

```
If val IsNot Nothing AndAlso val.Count > 0 Then
```